# How to give different color to a part of sentence?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a sentence. For eg: "ABCD is a place where i live. ABCD is known for tourism". I need to give the 2nd "ABCD" a blue color and set this whole sentence to a textview.The thing is -the word which needs to be colored is dynamic, we will get the word from response. and if the word is repeating in sentence and if i need to give a particular one(suppose i get the position from response) a blue color, what is the practical way.

```
var title2 = "ABCD is a place where i live. ABCD is known for tourism"
var title3 = "ABCD"
var spannableString = SpannableString(title2)
                spannableString.setSpan(
                    ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE),
                    title2.indexOf(title3),
                    title2.indexOf(title3)+title3.length,
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                )
textview.text = spannableString
```

So according to my code,only 1st ABCD gets blue color. But I need to give only the 2nd "ABCD" a blue color

Comment: Are you using xml or jetpack compose for UI

Comment: xml for now. The thing is -the word which needs to be colored is dynamic, we will get the word from response. and if the word is repeating in sentence and if i need to give a particular one a blue color, what is the practical way.

Comment: **USE THIS**

text.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#2a89ff'>dynamic text goes here</font>") + " your normal text here");

Answer (score 1):

`indexOf` returns the first occurence of the specified string. To get the second, you can indicate the index from where to start searching from as second argument of `indexOf`. For example like

```
var spannableString = SpannableString(title2)
                spannableString.setSpan(
                    ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE),
                    title2.indexOf(title3, 1),
                    title2.indexOf(title3, 1) + title3.length,
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                )
```

If the first occurence isn't at the start of the `String` you could write this instead

```
var spannableString = SpannableString(title2)
                spannableString.setSpan(
                    ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE),
                    title2.indexOf(title3, title2.indexOf(title3) + 1),
                    title2.indexOf(title3, title2.indexOf(title3) + 1) + title3.length,
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                )
```